# Procedure that will use an inside output to create a view

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, view

I want to achieve the following. I have an application that uses chats and I want to display to the logged-in user his chats in which he is involved. 
I have a table named:
 - CHAT_USER where I store the ID of the conversation & user and 
 - CHAT where I have the Topic and other information.
My approach is to get the list of chat IDs by selecting in the first instance what I received from the parameters and then use that output to create a view with the active chats.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`mysql`@`%` PROCEDURE `GetChats`(
    IN userName VARCHAR(60), 
    IN ticket INT) 
NOT DETERMINISTIC CONTAINS SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
BEGIN
SELECT 
   ( select `CHAT_USER_ID`, `CHAT_ID`, `TICKET_ID`, `USER` from `CHAT_USER` 
        where `USER`= userName and `TICKET_ID` = ticket ) as ChatsForUser ,
   (select `r`.`CHAT_ID` ,
            `l`.`CHAT_TYPE` ,
            `r`.`TICKET_ID`,
            group_concat(`r`.`USER` separator ',') AS `USER`,
            `l`.`IS_PUBLIC` ,
            `r`.`IS_ACTIV` ,
            `l`.`CHAT_TOPIC` 
                from (`CHAT_USER` `r` left join `CHAT` `l` on((`r`.CHAT_ID` = `l`.`CHAT_ID`))) 
                where ((`r`.`IS_ACTIV` = '1') and (`r`.`USER_TYPE` <> 'INITIATOR')) 
                group by `r`.`CHAT_ID` having `r`.`CHAT_ID` IN ChatsForUser.`CHAT_ID`) as OutputChats;

       COMMIT;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

More info:

```
Table CHAT_USER
===========================================================
CHAT_USER_ID | CHAT_ID | TICKET_ID | USER | ...other fields
===========================================================

Table CHAT
============================================================================
CHAT_ID | TICKET_ID | CHAT_TYPE | CHAT_TOPIC | IS_ACTIV | IS_PUBLIC | other fields
============================================================================

I want an output that will have this:
===============================================================
CHAT_ID | TICKET_ID | USERS | IS_ACTIV | IS_PUBLIC | CHAT_TOPIC
===============================================================
```

CONDITIONS:
To display active CHAT_IDs on a TICKET, where the logged-in user is involved in conversation.
An example of output should return only the first 2 rows, because ME is involved in the discussions:

```
12 | 234 | me, user1, user 4  | 1 | 1 | Problem 1
14 | 234 | me, user56, user 9 | 1 | 1 | Problem 233
19 | 234 | user44, user 19    | 1 | 1 | Problem 12
22 | 234 | user33, user 22    | 1 | 1 | Problem 230
```

Is this possible? If not, can give some ideas how to achieve this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you try to make an dbfiddle example. and what you want for a result. At least both selects can be done in one, as far as i can see. Use teh first select as basis for chat_user. But with an example i find it strange that there is in chat_user a topic_id and a topic(which i would expect to be in a tabletopic.

Comment: I've improved the question by adding more details @nbk

Answer (score 1):

You can try following Select statement before you start with your procedure and see if it returns the wanted data. The testing only is possible with actual data and the wanted result.

```
SELECT 
  c.CHAT_ID,c.TICKET_ID
  ,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Cu.USER  ORDER BY Cu.USER  SEPARATOR ', '),
  MAX(cu.IS_ACTIV), MAX(cu.IS_PUBLIC),MAX(cu.CHAT_TOPIC)
FROM CHAT C inner join CHAT_USER cu 
On c.CHAT_ID = cu.CHAT_ID and c.TICKET_ID  =cu.TICKET_ID;
GROUP BY c.CHAT_ID,c.TICKET_ID
```

try this if it gives you the expected result

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`mysql`@`%` PROCEDURE `GetChats`(
    IN userName VARCHAR(60), 
    IN ticket INT) 
NOT DETERMINISTIC CONTAINS SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
BEGIN

SELECT 
  c.CHAT_ID,c.TICKET_ID
  ,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Cu.USER  ORDER BY Cu.USER  SEPARATOR ', '),
  MAX(c.IS_ACTIV), MAX(c.IS_PUBLIC),MAX(c.CHAT_TOPIC)
FROM CHAT C 
inner join (SELECT * FROM CHAT_USER WHERE `CHAT_ID` 
         in 
         (SELECT `CHAT_ID` FROM  CHAT_USER WHERE `USER` Like userName )) cu 
On c.CHAT_ID = cu.CHAT_ID and c.TICKET_ID  =cu.TICKET_ID
WHERE c.TICKET_ID = ticket
GROUP BY c.CHAT_ID,c.TICKET_ID;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

This procedure will give you all the chats and users to a specific ticket id.
As i said in the comment. i don't completely understand your stored procedure.

Comment: is working, but how I make the procedure to pass the parameters. Sorry to bother you , maybe, with simple stuff. But this is my first procedure

Comment: i changed the procedure  to fit at least a bit to that what you started.

Comment: I think we are close. I've added more info about the output. Now the SP is returning 4 rows, instead of the first 2. See the example above in the question.